# Vaadin with ArrayList component?

Tags: java, jpa, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm using JPAContainer and BeanFieldGroup. I have a bean with an attribute `@ElementCollection`. In this attribute I add cell phone numbers and I want to show this values in some component after added.

I tried create a TextField and Button to add, this works but I don't know how I display the values. I think a TextArea but I don't know if a best solution.

How to this ?

here my bean

```
@Entity
public class UnidadeEscolar implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull @NotEmpty @Size(min=5, max=50) @Column(unique=true)
    private String nome;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Departamento departamento;

    private String cep;
    private String endereco;
    private String numero;
    private String complemento;
    private String bairro;
    private String cidade;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EstadosDoBrasil uf;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="tf_unescolar", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_unescolar"))
    @Column(name="telefone")
    private List<String> cellPhone = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String email;
    private String status;

    public UnidadeEscolar() {
        this(0L, "", Departamento.ESTADUAL, 
                "", "", "", "", 
                "", "", EstadosDoBrasil.AC, 
                new ArrayList<String>(), "");
    }

    public UnidadeEscolar(Long id, String nome, Departamento departamento,
            String cep, String endereco, String numero, String complemento,
            String bairro, String cidade, EstadosDoBrasil uf,
            List<String> cellPhone, String email) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.departamento = departamento;
        this.cep = cep;
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.complemento = complemento;
        this.bairro = bairro;
        this.cidade = cidade;
        this.uf = uf;
        this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
        this.email = email;
    }

    /** add cell phone number **/
    public void addCellPhoneContact(String tf){
        cellPhone.add(tf);
    }

    public List<String> getCellPhone{
          return cellPhone;
    }

}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: There are many ways to display your cell-phones. You could add a label, a textarea, a (simple) table, a combobox... This is a domain specific question and can't be answered in general.

Comment: @nexus searching a solution I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hz630Oz2Q0 he use `@Embbedable` and after `@ElementCollection`, when he changed to collection a table was added, how he did this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just write a component to do the same.

It's tied to JDAL (it's a JDAL View) but you could use the code as guide.

Note that I use the `doRefresh()` method to move data from model to view and `doUpdate()` method to move data from view to model.

[StringListView.java](https://github.com/chelu/jdal/blob/master/vaadin/src/main/java/org/jdal/vaadin/ui/StringListView.java)

[image: StringListView]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I created a strategy to add and show my telphones. Example of Jose Luis Martin help me

here how I did

```
public class TableListView extends VerticalLayout implements Button.ClickListener, ItemClickListener, ValueChangeListener{  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Button add;
    private Button delete;
    private HorizontalLayout buttonLayout;
    private TelefoneField txtField;
    private Table tabela;
    private UnidadeEscolar bean;
    private Integer tableItem;
    private CheckBox add9;


    public TableListView(UnidadeEscolar bean){
        this.bean = bean;   
        buildMainLayout();
    }


    private void buildMainLayout(){
        setSpacing(false);
        tabela = new Table("");
        tabela.setHeight("100px");
        tabela.setWidth("200px");
        tabela.addContainerProperty("Telefone", String.class, null);
        tabela.setSelectable(true);
        tabela.addItemClickListener(this);

        addComponent(tabela);
        addComponent(buildButtonLayout());      
    }

    private HorizontalLayout buildButtonLayout(){
        buttonLayout = new HorizontalLayout();      
        txtField = new TelefoneField();
        txtField.setAdd9(true);
        add = new Button("+");
        delete = new Button("-");
        add9 = new CheckBox("Adiciona9", true);
        //listeners
        add9.addValueChangeListener(this);
        add.addClickListener(this);
        delete.addClickListener(this);

        buttonLayout.addComponent(txtField);
        buttonLayout.addComponent(add);
        buttonLayout.addComponent(delete);
        buttonLayout.addComponent(add9);
        return buttonLayout;
    }



    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        if(event.getButton() == add){           
            if(txtField.getValue().trim().isEmpty()){
                Notification.show("Insira o número do telefone");
            }else{
                Object addItem = tabela.addItem();
                tabela.getItem(addItem).getItemProperty("Telefone").setValue(txtField.getValue());
                bean.addTelefoneContato(txtField.getValue());
                txtField.setValue("");
            }           
        }

        if(event.getButton() == delete){            
            tabela.removeItem(tableItem);
            bean.removeTelefoneContato(tableItem);
        }       
    }


    @Override
    public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
        tableItem = Integer.parseInt(event.getItemId().toString());
    }


    @Override
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        boolean value = (Boolean) event.getProperty().getValue();
        txtField.setAdd9(value);        
    }
```

And the result is: [image]